# Need help updating action payload array in redux reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I have got an array of posts that returns from my API, that looks something like this:

```
[
   {
     "id": 4311,
     "title": "C43- Miami Bow Cabinet Handles High Quality Stainless Steel (Polished) Handles",
     "liked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2235,
      "title": "C43- Miami Bow Cabinet Handles High Quality Stainless Steel (Brushed) Handles",
      "liked": false
    }
]
```

Then I have another stored array called 'wishlist' which looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 4311,
      "title": "C43- Miami Bow Cabinet Handles High Quality Stainless Steel (Polished) Handles",
      "liked": true
    }
]
```

What I want to do is test if each post is in the wishlist array and updated the 'liked' key for that post. In this case the post with id 4311 is in the wishlist array so should have its key 'liked' updated to true. I can't do arr.includes() because a post from the posts array would not match a post in the wishlist array (because the 'liked' keys arent the same).

So here is what I was thinking:

1. Normalize the wishlist by ID's
2. Then map the posts array and check if the id's match
3. Update the liked key for that post

I have got steps 1 & 2 downpat, here is my javascript:

```
  // lets normalize our list of ids
  let wishlistByID = state.wishlist.map(function(post) {
    return post['id']                      
  })

  // now lets map our posts array and see if the id's match
  let inWishlist = action.posts.map(function(post) {
    return wishlistByID.includes(post['id'])
// returns true when they match
  })
```

But I am unsure on how to do step 3. For reference here is my reducer:

```
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: action.posts,
    isFetching: false,
  }
```

Any help appreciated - this also resolves another open question I have

**Update - thanks to help from @Giang Lee I created a new posts constant which maps through the posts and if that post has an id that matches the wishlistByID array then just updates the liked key.

```
  // lets normalize our list of ids
  let wishlistByID = state.wishlist.map(function(post) {
    return post['id']                      
  })

  // now lets map our posts array and see if the id's match
  // den just up the liked key to true
  const posts = action.posts.map(function(post) {
    if(wishlistByID.includes(post['id'])) {
      post['liked'] = true
    }
    return post
  })   

  return {
    ...state,
    posts: posts,
    isFetching: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

try my way

```
const posts = state.posts.map((item) => {
 const post = action.posts.find(p => p.id === item.id);
 return post ? post : item;
});

return {
    ...state,
    posts,
    isFetching: false,
  }
```

Comment: Are you able to expand on this code, I'm not 100% certain how this would link up with what i have already

Comment: sorry i was misunderstood. answer was edited. My way is return new posts by use "map" and check if post in state in actions.posts by "find(p => p.id === item.id)".

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used your methodology but slightly different and solved it!.